# CASE statement in Access 2013 (and how to use it)?

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement, case, ms-access-2013

I'm new to Microsoft Access programming.

I want to check a date field and return if it is

- today, or
- yesterday, or
- last week (the date within last week's dates), or
- last month, or
- it's older than a month

I made the code below: (using expression Builder)

```
 Expr_Timeout: 
    IIf([Report_DateTime]=Date(),"Today","")+
    IIf([Report_DateTime]=Date()-1,"Yesterday","")+
    IIf([Report_DateTime]<Date()-7,"Last Week","")+
    IIf([Report_DateTime]<Date()-30,"Last Month","")+
    IIf([Report_DateTime]<Date()-31,"Old","")
```

Is there a better way to do this? Other languages have a CASE statement but I'm not sure how to do it in Access. I'm using access 2013.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for Gord Thompson for giving me a clue, this is what I was looking for, it's working perfect :

```
expr1: Switch([date_]=Date(),"today",
              [date_]=Date()-1,"yesterday",
              [date_]>Date()-7,"week ago")
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a `Switch()` function that you can use in Access SQL queries and in VBA code (ref: [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx)).

Example:

```
Switch([Report_DateTime]=Date(), "Today", [Report_DateTime]=Date()-1, "Yesterday", [Report_DateTime]<Date()-1, "Before Yesterday")
```

There is also a `Select Case` construct in VBA (ref: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278454.aspx)).

Example:

```
Select Case [Report_DateTime]
    Case Date()
        status = "Today"
    Case Date() - 1
        status = "Yesterday"
    Case < (Date() - 1)
        status = "Before Yesterday"
End Select
```

Comment: I've tried urs today and similar before but I get the error massage "The syntax of the subquery in this expression is incorrect", that's why I'm asking how to do it. Thanks anyway

Comment: plus there is no Select Case Expression!